# How to lazy load init code of programs in bash?

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to use `ros`, `conda`, `pyenv` or other programs that require you to source some kind of init code before you use them. But adding all of their init codes into `.bashrc` seems cumbersome at best and impractical at worst ( `conda` specifically takes few seconds to init ).

Best case scenario, I would have some sort of function like this:

```bsh
ros2 () {
  # Info
  echo "First ros2 call, sourcing necessary files..."
  
  # Source ros2 environment
  source /opt/ros/eloquent/setup.bash
  
  # Remove this function
  unset -f ros2
  
  # Run was originally intended
  /opt/ros/eloquent/bin/ros2 $@
}
```

Intention was:

- First call gets redirected towards a function which will do the necessary setup, then delete itself
- Subsequent calls will not go trough this wrapper function

This however does work, due to `unset` not affecting the parent shell I assume.

Is there any other way how to deal with programs requiring init code automatically (in bash and / or zsh) ?

Comment: If ros2 is a function, it does affect the shell that calls it. Why don't you just test some variable that is set in `setup.bash`? If the variable exists, you don't run `setup.bash`.

Comment: I clarified, ros2 is a regular program ( not in this case, but without loss of generality lets say it is ), however it is not in PATH ( and also it needs some additional setup of shell to work properly, so the traditional way of doing it is to just source /opt/ros/... when necessary but that is tedious

Comment: This doesn't change what I said.

Answer (score 0):

So it's not pretty but I found a workaround

```
alias ros2='[ -z $ROS_SOURCED ] && source /opt/ros/eloquent/setup.bash; ROS_SOURCED=1;ros2'
```

This takes care of the source and keeps track of whether it was sourced.